# Google.GData.Documents.DocumentService.Query() hangs in multithreading

Tags: gdata, google-docs-api

I am tying to download documents of multiple users simultaneously using threading.
The application download documents for some users and eventually all the threads get stuck at the following statement.

Google.GData.Documents.DocumentService.Query()

However if I try to download them one user after the other (no threading). It downloads just fine. Every thread has its own instance of DocumentFeed, DocumentsListQuery,Document Service etc

The application is developed in c#. What could be the possible reason for it to get stuck on the "query()" statement?

Comment: Is there any download limit for a given gapps user? Can that cause this issue?

Comment: I don't know if this will help or not. I have generally found that when I have multiple threads running, it helps to put **Application.DoEvents** in several places to allow other parts of the code to run.